# Trying to start backburner server for Rails application and failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just created a new rails application using command:

```
rails blog
```

Now I'm following blog/README file. To get started, I'm trying to start backburner server as stated in the README file:

- Change directory into myapp and start the web server: script/server (run with --help for options)

Using the `server` command I started backburner server with default settings:

- Manager Port: 3234
- Server Port: 3233
- 255.255.255.0 as subnet mask, with `Automatic Search` checked

The backburner server window keep posting the following information:

```
INF Looking for a manager using 10.65.97.255:3234
```

And after a while:

```
WRN Manager is not responding
```

Seems the server never started because I cannot find a page in `http://localhost:3000/` address. How to configure and start backburner server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages you've posted appear to relate to Autodesk Backburner and are not being output by Rails. Make sure you are running `script/server` from the `blog` directory and not just `server`.

Comment: forgot to mention that my OS is Windows 7 Ultimate where I should use "ruby script/server".